# There is any standard report to print Invt. Receipts and Posted Invt. Receipts?

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, dynamics-business-central

In Business Central, there is any standard report to print Invt. Receipts and Posted Invt. Receipts?

I see that by default there is no configured report in report selections:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there does not appear to be any standard reports for `Invt. Receipts` and `Posted Invt. Receipts` in Business Central 21.5 (newest version as of 2023-03-08).

A `report` would have to be developed.

You could use `Inventory Put-aways` instead and then you can print the `Inventory Put-away List`.